# Single Role Spring Security Implementation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've been working on spring boot mini-project and I'm stuck at this part.

So our project may contain many users but each user can only have one role

There are three roles:

- TRAINEE
- FACILITATOR
- ADMIN

**ERD included:**

[image: ERD]

My question is can I implement Spring security registration and authorization based on my ERD because from what I've seen from tutorials in the internet has many-to-many relationship between user and role entity or my ERD is wrong?

Hopefully someone could enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. Create your own implementation of `Authentication`
2. The interface defineds method `getAuthorities()`. It returns a `Collection` but it's up to you how you implement it.
3. Make sure your Login filter (or whatever authentication mechanism you may have in place) returns your custom `AuthenticatedUser` (instead of a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` you may find in examples)

Example:

```java
public class AuthenticatedUser implements Authentication{
    private User user;
    public AuthenticatedUser(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
    } 
    // rest of the code omitted
}
```

I'm not sure I understand your reference to registration - user registration is usually a custom implementation anyway; you shouldn't have any issues there.